# Set height of div, relative to browser window height

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently this determines window height and sets the height of `.one` to 1/2 of the window height, and `.two` to 1/4 of the window height.

How could this be reformatted to use a percentage-based heights instead of the fractions?

I'd like to do something like 80%/20% or 70%/30%. Thanks in advance.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.one').css({'height':(($(window).height()/2))+'px'});
        $('.two').css({'height':(($(window).height()/4))+'px'});
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.one').css({'height':(($(window).height()/2))+'px'});
        $('.two').css({'height':(($(window).height()/4))+'px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Percentages are fractions, right? 1/4 == 25% == .25

Comment: Yes, they are! But I'm learning how these ideas are done in various ways. I'd like to know how this is achieved with percentage values. Thanks!

Comment: 20% is x*20/100, etc...

Comment: Shouldn't you at least put your code in a function and call the one function from both `.load()` and `.resize()` rather than duplicating your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I recommend to get the height of `window` on both the events first. And then apply the simple math calculations.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).bind("load resize", function(){
        _winHeight = $(window).height();

        // Setting Height
        $('.one').css({'height':_winHeight * 0.5}); // 0.5 = 50%, 0.8 = 80%
        $('.two').css({'height':_winHeight * 0.25}); // 0.25 = 25%
    });
});
```

or you can store the unit height of the window in the variable and the apply as much percentage as you want, like:

```
$(function(){
        $(window).bind("load resize", function(){
            _winHeight = $(window).height()/100;

            // Setting Height
            $('.one').css({'height':_winHeight * 50}); // 50% Height
            $('.two').css({'height':_winHeight * 25}); // 25% Height
        });
    });
```

**Tip:**

- try binding both load and resize events together, this will save your code length.
- Also, there is no need to mention unit px with height in jquery.

Good luck! Happy jQuery!!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use CSS?

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

.one{
    height: 50%;
}

.two {
    height: 25%;
}
```

Comment: CSS percentages work on the containing object height/width, NOT on the window height/width.  From what I think the OP is asking for, this will not accomplish it. If the document is longer than the window height, this will make the object way larger than a percentage of the window height.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.one').css({'height':($(window).height()/2)});
    });
 });
```

It is not necessary to say `'px'` in your coding. it won't take any effect.. if don't set it will take as pixel only. To reduct 50% height you can calculate it in fractions as `50/100=1/2` . So above coding will reduce your height 50%.. similary for 25% use `25/100=1/4`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk7Ve/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Lk7Ve/2/

This is for 50% and 25%. If you want it for 80% and 20%, you'll have to multiply by (4/5) and (1/5) respectively.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.one').css({'height':(($(window).height()/2))+'px'});
    $('.two').css({'height':(($(window).height()/4))+'px'});
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.one').css({'height':(($(window).height()/2))+'px'});
    $('.two').css({'height':(($(window).height()/4))+'px'});
});
```

For 80% and 20%

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.one').css({'height':(($(window).height() * (4/5)))+'px'});
    $('.two').css({'height':(($(window).height() * (1/5)))+'px'});
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.one').css({'height':(($(window).height() * (4/5)))+'px'});
    $('.two').css({'height':(($(window).height() * (1/5)))+'px'});
});
```

Comment: Why have exact duplicates of the same code?  Shouldn't you at least make a common function that you call from both events?

Comment: Coz I wasn't sure what OP wanted. Just for his clarity, I wanted to show them separatly