# Set div height to window height (Not 100% with CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to get the window height with jQuery/JavaScript (which I'm not good at) and apply it to a few divs (3-4) with class 'slide'. Why I don't want to use `height: 100%;` in CSS is because some elements get covered by the ones that have height to 100%: [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/63cmlz) (I could make the footer 100% high but that would be a mess) and also because the height changes with zooming in/out (i.e. instead of staying for example 1080p, it changes to 100% and still fills window when zooming out).

So then I found some answers here on stackoverflow, and some people were suggesting something like this: (from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860892/set-height-of-div-relative-to-browser-window-height))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".slide").css("height", $(window).height());
});
$(window).resize(function(){
 $('.slide').css('height':($(window).height());
});
```

I've edited it a bit.

I read a bunch of other posts on the same problem, and tried everything, but nothing seems to work for me. Even made a new set of files to test this alone, look at it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gLffpjw/1/).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code in your question is correct, but the code in your fiddle is wrong: You've used a `:` where you want a `,` (and separately, you haven't included jQuery in your fiddle).

The code should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slide').css('height', $(window).height());
    // Comma, not colon ----^
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.slide').css('height', $(window).height());
    // Comma, not colon ----^
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gLffpjw/2/) *(I added a background to .slide so you could see it's the full height)*

Note that in the fiddle you end up with scrollbars, because of the default padding on `body`. But I assume in your real site/app, you're dealing with that in CSS.

Comment: Hmm, I have to make a <script> element in the html and put the code there to make it work. For some reason l can't link it with
`<script type="text/javascript" src"../js/windowHeight.js"></script>`

Comment: @MarinBelec: Assuming the file is on that path, that should be fine (although you should remove the `type` attribute; the default is JavaScript). Look in your web console for file loading errors.